# Why I can't set PrimeNG p-calenar component CSS style?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am working on an Angular project using PrimeNG and I am finding the following problem trying to give the correct CSS style to a **p-calendar** component into my page.

Basically into my HTML code I have something like this:

```
<tr class="search-box">
  <th></th>
  <th>
    <p-calendar inputStyleClass="dateTimeField"  (onSelect)="onDateSelect($event)" (onClearClick)="dt.filter('', 'date', 'equals')" [showButtonBar]="true" placeholder="Search by Data inserimento" [readonlyInput]="true" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"></p-calendar>
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'name', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Name" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'company.name', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Company" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'company.BU.name', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by BU" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'dettaglio_ordine.commessa.code', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Commessa" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'dettaglio_ordine.cliente', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Cliente" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'dettaglio_ordine.cliente_finale', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Cliente Finale" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'dettaglio_ordine.importo_contratto', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Search by Importo Contratto" class="p-column-filter">
  </th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
```

As you can see the second th tag contains this **p-calendar** component:

```
<p-calendar inputStyleClass="dateTimeField"  (onSelect)="onDateSelect($event)" (onClearClick)="dt.filter('', 'date', 'equals')" [showButtonBar]="true" placeholder="Search by Data inserimento" [readonlyInput]="true" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"></p-calendar>
```

I am going crazy trying to set a style for this component. Differently from the other following **input** tag I am not able to corretly set the style (basically the width and the font size).

I was trying to do as shown here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=2610

So into my CSS code I put:

```
.dateTimeField {
  width: 80% !important;
}
```

I also tried to set the **styleClass="dateTimeField"** on the **p-calendar** component tag and then set the:

```
.dateTimeField input {
  width: 80% !important;
}
```

but it still not working and I obtain this wrong visualization:

[image]

As you can see it is too large, it is not taking my CSS settings. The strange thing is that if using the Chrome tools I can set the correct width by:

```
input.ng-tns-c59-5.dateTimeField.ui-inputtext.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ng-star-inserted {
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

but if I try to copy and paste this CSS settings into the CSS file of my Angular component still not work.

How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is the encapsulation.

You should put your css rules in your global `style.css`, otherwise
Angular by default will hide the styles of one component to another when view-encapsulation has it's default values in the components.

That's the reason you see the `ng-tns-c59-5` inside your dev tools.

See that example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-calendar-svpn8n?file=src/styles.css

For more info: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself...I put the style related this particular component into the CSS of the specific component global defining it as:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .dateTimeField {
    width: 80% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't the answer above satisfied your needs?

Comment: @StPaulis I used this other way that in some way is based also on your answer... I think that in this way I handle better the CSS style because I want avoid to modify the global style for a style that is related only to a specific component. If you add my solution to your question I will be happy to accept it :-)

Comment: It is OK... I just wanted to know If there was a problem with my solution.
I understand your point of you, you could play with the encapsulation of your component, to avoid `:host` and `::ng-deep` and have your styles inside your component as you want. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @StPaulis in any case I accepted your ansewr because I had the inspiration reading it (I am not a real frontender...more a backender...when I read it I undertood the cause of the error and how I fixed something similar in the past